# Which is more efficient, mutationObserver or proxy object?

Tags: javascript

This is my first time opening a question here, as I didn't find a question similar to mine I decided to create it.

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I'm in doubt of which method to use to identify a change in an HTML attribute, like `aria-hidden`. I need to identify when a given element with `aria-hidden` changes its value and then define a behavior for when that happens.

In my case I need observe only one or two elements that needs to be modified. I try the `mutationObserver` and Proxy Object, but I would like to know which one would be more efficient or if there is another way to solve this, I know that on this occasion efficiency is not a problem, but it would help me to better understand which occasion to use each one.

Comment: I suggest you ignore this, and just do whichever one allows you to write simpler code.

Comment: As a beginner, you should invert how you’re thinking about your problem. Rather than observe and respond to the change in the HTML attribute, you should think about either observing and responding to the event that actually causes the change in the HTML attribute or, better yet, figure out a way to have the thing that caused the HTML attribute to change to also call your function (the one you have right now that you want to “respond to the change”). Well designed event driven programming isn’t easy for experienced engineers, so I’d definitely avoid it as a beginnner

Comment: A proxy object simply won't work for observing changes to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MutationObserver` is more appropriate when you watch DOM changes, also it could be more efficient since you can observe DOM trees rather than one element. Also you can observe adding new DOM elements and watch them too. Overall `MutationObserver` offers wider range of scenarios with ability to progressively extend complexity of existing logic.

The problem with `Proxy` that you should use a proxy for mutating an attribute, but attributes could be mutated with different ways and also by some script. The same goes with decorators (hooking into the properties and methods of an existing DOM node):

```js
new MutationObserver(list => {

  console.log(`I'm a MutationObserver and I don't care how you mutate the 'aria-hidden' attribute`);

}).observe($test, {attributeFilter: ['aria-hidden']});
```

```html
<div id="$test" aria-hidden></div>

<!-- it's difficult to proxy or decorate all possible ways of mutations -->

<button onclick="$test.attributes.getNamedItem('aria-hidden').value = 'false';console.log($test)">Set false</button>
<button onclick="$test.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');console.log($test)">Set true</button>
```